# Lost Planet 2: Camera in splitscreen too small

Tags: version-differences, lost-planet-2

On the XBox 360 version of Lost Planet 2, each screen in splitscreen co-op mode only takes up a quarter of the screen, with the other quarter being taken up by each player's minimap. Is there any way to change this, or is it an inherent flaw in the game?

Does the PC version have this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always a problem when split screening. Unfortunatly there is no fix for this. The only solution would be onine co-op or get a hold of another 360 and any old TV and connect them together. By connecting them together you can play via "system link" or LAN which is basicly the same as online play but doesn't require the internet or a Xbox Live account.